# Android OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, memory-management

Is there any way to handle `OutOfMemoryException` in Android while using Bitmap of large number of pictures. I tried all the solutions given in this site ie(GC, Bitmap.reset()). I just want to know whether any alert can be generated before the heap memory is going to full? so that i can handle it in a different way.

Comment: Just a note: never ever catch OutOfMemoryException. That can lead to totally unexpected behaviour and is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Activity there is a callback function you can implement to be notified of low memory issues:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory()

```
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();

    // Your memory releasing code
}
```

Comment: Note this applies to the overall system.  It has almost no relation to a single app running out of managed heap space (which is what what cause an OOM).

Comment: -1. As fadden pointed out, this method won't get called even if your app is OOM.